# Language study technique questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can this site include questions about resources one would use to learn the Japanese Language?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-this-site-include-questions-about-resources-one-would-use-to-learn-the-japane)

We're going to be inundated with "How do you learn those 4-character buddhist sayings?" "What is the best flashcard app?", and other "teach me how to learn" questions. I'll be stunned if we don't have a heisig-related battle at some point.

I would argue these are not answerable questions, unless we want to drag learning/cognitive research into the discussion.

Comment: This is arguably a dup of the only other meta question... http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-this-site-include-questions-about-resources-one-would-use-to-learn-the-japane

Comment: Agreed with @jkerian. I'm happy with the compromise of marking what's subjective and unanswerable as such, and putting any useful stuff we find in community wiki.